# online hotel room booking concept in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am working with online hotel room booking concept

**room(table)**

```
roomId name  Price   Totalrooms      
1       A    100        10
2       B    150        20
```

How could I build the database to allow for users to search for the availability of a room (with a from and to date)? Also, what would be the best table structure for storing bookings?

Comment: You need to clearly state your question -- are you after how to get rooms between dates when your table has no such information to compare, or the entire data model which is IMO too broad a question.

Comment: If this is a legit question, you're going to have to give us a lot more to work with.  I don't think anyone is going to dash off a quick hotel room booking system for you.

Comment: And I can't even figure out what "Totalrooms" is supposed to be.

Comment: For something as complex, and commonplace, as this, I would use a prebuilt booking system. No point reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

You need another table with bookings

```
  ID      roomId        checkInDate          checkOutDate
  1       1             4/6/2011 12:00PM     4/9/2011 11:00AM
  2       2             4/2/2011 12:00PM     4/3/2011 11:00AM
  3       1             4/9/2011 12:00PM     4/11/2011 11:00AM
```

Then when you add a new booking for each room, you need to make sure the following query results in a `zero 0`, or else the room is already booked.

```
//Count Scheduling Conflicts
select count(roomid) from bookings where 
    bookings.checkOutDate > YouNewBookingCheckInDate and
    bookings.checkInDate < YouNewBookingCheckOutDate
```

So if your new booking request for Room 1 is on `4/5/2011 1:00PM`, record #1 will be counted and the query will result in a 1 (indicating 1 conflict)

Comment: can't you do `select 1 from`... to avoid the unnecessary count? it won't return anything if there's no match IIRC