# prevent race condition in online hotel booking

Tags: php, mysql, race-condition

I asked this question before and people gave me a solution to my problem but now my problem has changes. Before I had a table called rooms in my database. It had a `hold` field where when someone is making a reservation, i put a time 15 mins in the future to keep it for that user. The room becomes available again if that user doesn't finish the reservation in 15 mins. It was the solution to my previous problem.

But now I no longer have a rooms table. I only have roomtype and reservations table. Roomtype got name price info # of rooms and of course id fields. The reservations table got checkin checkout roomtypeid and info about the user. Since I don't have the rooms table I can't figure out a way to prevent multiple users from booking a single room at the same time.

My question is how can I prevent race conditions without the rooms table? If it is not too much to ask I would like the solution to be only sql and php.
[Here is a link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832570/how-to-prevent-race-condition-in-online-hotel-booking)

EDIT: I found this post and that's why I don't have the rooms table anymore. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784372/online-hotel-room-booking-concept-in-php)

Comment: Sounds like you could just add a preliminary reservation into your reservations table, and expire that after 15 minutes.

Comment: The rooms table does seem to be an important table to keep everything together; why did you remove it?

Comment: @Jack I removed it because I no longer needed it. Also I found a better way to keep track of how many rooms are available and how many are not.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The way I did it before I just kept updating the hold field. So I didnt have to insert or delete anything. I just checked the field and if it was available I would update it. I was wondering if I could find a solution similar to that so I don't have to write something that deletes entries from the db periodically. On my other post I was suggested to use cronjob but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: when u use transaction table will be locked.

Comment: @ArunKillu I only know so much about transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add a temporary reservation to the reservations table (with a temp-flag/field) and remove that later if the reservation is not finished after 15 minutes.

additionally if multiple users try to reserve the last room very simultaneously you should again check the availability in every step of the reservation to notify users that the last room has just been taken and propose another roomtype etc.

Comment: Thanks. After a lot of thought I ended up adding 2 fields. One is to check if the reservation is paid and the other is to check if someone is reserving a room right now. The concern I had in my previous question was that what if someone left the reservation in the middle of it. It is all solved and figured out thanks to you and guys like you who help other people and answer their questions on SO.